# Unable to perform Data Import Handler in Apache Solr with Oracle Data Base

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr8.4.1

I have an Oracle DB to be imported into Apache Solr . Have the below code in solrconfig.xml ;

```
        </requestHandler>

        <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
        <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-8.4.1.jar" />
        <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-8.4.1.-extras.jar" />

       <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
          <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
          </lst>
        </requestHandler>
```

and the data-config.xml as ;

```
enter 
        <dataConfig>
        <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
                driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:serviceid" 
                user="username" 
                password="password"/>  
                <document>
           <entity name="tablename"  
            pk="CUST_SYS_ID"
              query="select     REC_VERSION,CUST_SYS_ID,CUST_CODE,CUST_APPR_UID,CUST_APPR_DTM,CUST_APPR_STS,CUST_DFLT_BROK_CODE,CUST_MAILING_ADDR,CUST_PARENT_CUST_CODE,CUST_LINK_CUST_CODE,CUST_MC_CODE,CUST_NAME,CUST_SHORT_NAME,CUST_CONS_CODE,CUST_ATTACHED_TO,CUST_DFLT_YN,CUST_CREDIT_CHK_YN,CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT,CUST_CREDIT_CASH,CUST_ANNUAL_INCOME,CUST_COMMERCIAL_YN,CUST_FRZ_FLAG,CUST_FRZ_PERMANENT_YN,CUST_FRZ_REASON,CUST_EFF_FM_DTM,CUST_EFF_TO_DTM,CUST_ISO_RATING,CUST_RI_TYPE,CUST_INTER_OFFICE_YN,CUST_LOCAL_YN,CUST_TAX_ID,CUST_FIRST_NAME,CUST_MIDDLE_NAME,CUST_LAST_NAME,CUST_TITLE,CUST_SUFFIX,CUST_SSN_NO,CUST_PROFESSION,CUST_QUALIFICATION,CUST_DOB,CUST_GENDER,CUST_MARITAL_STS,CUST_ALL_CURR_APPL_YN,CUST_TAX_STS,CUST_LOCATION,CUST_PIN_NUMBER,CUST_GRP_COMP_CODE,CUST_GROUP_CODE,CUST_PAN_NO,CUST_CREDIT_DAYS,CUST_PASSPORT_NO,CUST_ASSR_YN,CUST_CIVIL_ID,CUST_CIVIL_ID_TYPE,CUST_REF_NO,CUST_MARKETER_CODE,CUST_PF_NO,CUST_COMM_REG_NO,CUST_CORP_APPR_CUST_YN,CUST_JOB,CUST_NATIONALITY,CUST_OCC_TYPE,CUST_CHANNEL,CUST_SUB_CHANNEL,CUST_TAX_YN,CUST_EMAIL_YN,CUST_SMS_YN,CUST_VER_NO,CUST_RESIDENT_YN,CUST_OWN_AC_YN,CUST_OWN_CAR_YN,CUST_OWN_HOUSE_YN,CUST_OWN_REFRIGERATOR_YN,CUST_OWN_TWO_WHEELER_YN,CUST_OWN_WASHING_MC_YN,CUST_TRAVEL_ABROAD,CUST_PASSPORT_EXPIRY_DTM,CUST_CONTACT_TYPE,CUST_STS,CUST_LEAD_YN,CUST_OTH_PROD_YN,CUST_VIP_YN,CUST_EMP_YN,CUST_CAPACITY,CUST_CSI_YN,CUST_CSI_LAST_DTM,CUST_REMARKS,CUST_AUTO_REN_PROC_DAY,CUST_NON_REN_NOTICE_DAY,CUST_TIN,CUST_PREF_MODE_OF_PAY,CR_UID,CR_DTM,UPD_UID,UPD_DTM,WF_PROCESS_ID,CUST_LEAD_CODE,CUST_REG_EXP_DTM,CUST_CIVIL_ID_EXPIRY_DTM,CUST_PARENT_ACC,CUST_PARENT_ACC_ID,CUST_TYPE,CUST_CAPITAL,CUST_ELECTRONIC_NO,CUST_CR_NO,CUST_BUSE_NATURE,CUST_PLACE_OF_ISSUE,CUST_NO_OF_EMP,CUST_REVENUE,CUST_ADDL_NO,CUST_OWNER_ID,CUST_IQAMA_NO,CUST_HIJRI,CUST_EDUCAT_LVL,CUST_WORK_PLACE,CUST_DFLT_CC_CODE,CUST_REG_FM_DTM,CUST_ADDL_TYPE,CUST_BUS_NAT,CUST_HIJRI_DTM,CUST_THIRD_NAME,CUST_DB_CR_ACC_TYPE,CUST_SUB_LED_TYPE,CUST_COMP_TYPE,CUST_VIP_REMARKS,CUST_BLOOD_GROUP,CUST_DEBIT_DAYS,CUST_DEBIT_LIMIT,CUST_VAT_TYPE,CUST_HIJRI_DOB,CUST_PROSPECT_YN,CUST_PROSPECT_NO,CUST_PHONE_NO,CUST_MOBILE_NO,CUST_ALTR_MOBILE_NO,CUST_MAIL_ID,CUST_ALTR_MAIL_ID,CUST_AR_FULL_NAME,CUST_ISSUED_IN,CUST_COMP_CLASS,REC_TYPE,CUST_REG_TO_DTM,CUST_AGENCY_TYPE from PCOM_CUSTOMER"
              deltaQuery="SELECT   REC_VERSION,CUST_SYS_ID,CUST_CODE,CUST_APPR_UID,CUST_APPR_DTM,CUST_APPR_STS,CUST_DFLT_BROK_CODE,CUST_MAILING_ADDR,CUST_PARENT_CUST_CODE,CUST_LINK_CUST_CODE,CUST_MC_CODE,CUST_NAME,CUST_SHORT_NAME,CUST_CONS_CODE,CUST_ATTACHED_TO,CUST_DFLT_YN,CUST_CREDIT_CHK_YN,CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT,CUST_CREDIT_CASH,CUST_ANNUAL_INCOME,CUST_COMMERCIAL_YN,CUST_FRZ_FLAG,CUST_FRZ_PERMANENT_YN,CUST_FRZ_REASON,CUST_EFF_FM_DTM,CUST_EFF_TO_DTM,CUST_ISO_RATING,CUST_RI_TYPE,CUST_INTER_OFFICE_YN,CUST_LOCAL_YN,CUST_TAX_ID,CUST_FIRST_NAME,CUST_MIDDLE_NAME,CUST_LAST_NAME,CUST_TITLE,CUST_SUFFIX,CUST_SSN_NO,CUST_PROFESSION,CUST_QUALIFICATION,CUST_DOB,CUST_GENDER,CUST_MARITAL_STS,CUST_ALL_CURR_APPL_YN,CUST_TAX_STS,CUST_LOCATION,CUST_PIN_NUMBER,CUST_GRP_COMP_CODE,CUST_GROUP_CODE,CUST_PAN_NO,CUST_CREDIT_DAYS,CUST_PASSPORT_NO,CUST_ASSR_YN,CUST_CIVIL_ID,CUST_CIVIL_ID_TYPE,CUST_REF_NO,CUST_MARKETER_CODE,CUST_PF_NO,CUST_COMM_REG_NO,CUST_CORP_APPR_CUST_YN,CUST_JOB,CUST_NATIONALITY,CUST_OCC_TYPE,CUST_CHANNEL,CUST_SUB_CHANNEL,CUST_TAX_YN,CUST_EMAIL_YN,CUST_SMS_YN,CUST_VER_NO,CUST_RESIDENT_YN,CUST_OWN_AC_YN,CUST_OWN_CAR_YN,CUST_OWN_HOUSE_YN,CUST_OWN_REFRIGERATOR_YN,CUST_OWN_TWO_WHEELER_YN,CUST_OWN_WASHING_MC_YN,CUST_TRAVEL_ABROAD,CUST_PASSPORT_EXPIRY_DTM,CUST_CONTACT_TYPE,CUST_STS,CUST_LEAD_YN,CUST_OTH_PROD_YN,CUST_VIP_YN,CUST_EMP_YN,CUST_CAPACITY,CUST_CSI_YN,CUST_CSI_LAST_DTM,CUST_REMARKS,CUST_AUTO_REN_PROC_DAY,CUST_NON_REN_NOTICE_DAY,CUST_TIN,CUST_PREF_MODE_OF_PAY,CR_UID,CR_DTM,UPD_UID,UPD_DTM,WF_PROCESS_ID,CUST_LEAD_CODE,CUST_REG_EXP_DTM,CUST_CIVIL_ID_EXPIRY_DTM,CUST_PARENT_ACC,CUST_PARENT_ACC_ID,CUST_TYPE,CUST_CAPITAL,CUST_ELECTRONIC_NO,CUST_CR_NO,CUST_BUSE_NATURE,CUST_PLACE_OF_ISSUE,CUST_NO_OF_EMP,CUST_REVENUE,CUST_ADDL_NO,CUST_OWNER_ID,CUST_IQAMA_NO,CUST_HIJRI,CUST_EDUCAT_LVL,CUST_WORK_PLACE,CUST_DFLT_CC_CODE,CUST_REG_FM_DTM,CUST_ADDL_TYPE,CUST_BUS_NAT,CUST_HIJRI_DTM,CUST_THIRD_NAME,CUST_DB_CR_ACC_TYPE,CUST_SUB_LED_TYPE,CUST_COMP_TYPE,CUST_VIP_REMARKS,CUST_BLOOD_GROUP,CUST_DEBIT_DAYS,CUST_DEBIT_LIMIT,CUST_VAT_TYPE,CUST_HIJRI_DOB,CUST_PROSPECT_YN,CUST_PROSPECT_NO,CUST_PHONE_NO,CUST_MOBILE_NO,CUST_ALTR_MOBILE_NO,CUST_MAIL_ID,CUST_ALTR_MAIL_ID,CUST_AR_FULL_NAME,CUST_ISSUED_IN,CUST_COMP_CLASS,REC_TYPE,CUST_REG_TO_DTM,CUST_AGENCY_TYPE FROM PCOM_CUSTOMER WHERE UPD_DTM > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">
         <field column="CUST_SYS_ID" type="strings" name="CUST_SYS_ID"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
         <field column="CUST_CODE" type="strings" name="CUST_CODE" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
           <field column="CUST_APPR_UID" type="strings" name="CUST_APPR_UID" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
         <field column="CUST_APPR_DTM" type="strings" name="CUST_APPR_DTM" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
           <field column="CUST_APPR_STS" type="strings" name="CUST_APPR_STS" indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_DFLT_BROK_CODE" type="strings" name="CUST_DFLT_BROK_CODE" indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_MAILING_ADDR" type="strings" name="CUST_MAILING_ADDR" indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_PARENT_CUST_CODE" type="strings" name="CUST_PARENT_CUST_CODE" indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_LINK_CUST_CODE" type="strings" name="CUST_LINK_CUST_CODE" indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_MC_CODE" type="strings" name="CUST_MC_CODE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_NAME" type="strings" name="CUST_NAME"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_SHORT_NAME" type="strings" name="CUST_SHORT_NAME"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CONS_CODE" type="strings" name="CUST_CONS_CODE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_ATTACHED_TO" type="strings" name="CUST_ATTACHED_TO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_DFLT_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_DFLT_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CREDIT_CHK_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_CREDIT_CHK_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT" type="strings" name="CUST_CREDIT_LIMIT"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CREDIT_CASH" type="strings" name="CUST_CREDIT_CASH"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_ANNUAL_INCOME" type="strings" name="CUST_ANNUAL_INCOME"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_COMMERCIAL_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_COMMERCIAL_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_FRZ_FLAG" type="strings" name="CUST_FRZ_FLAG"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_FRZ_PERMANENT_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_FRZ_PERMANENT_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_FRZ_REASON" type="strings" name="CUST_FRZ_REASON"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_EFF_FM_DTM" type="strings" name="CUST_EFF_FM_DTM"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_EFF_TO_DTM" type="strings" name="CUST_EFF_TO_DTM"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_ISO_RATING" type="strings" name="CUST_ISO_RATING"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_RI_TYPE" type="strings" name="CUST_RI_TYPE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_INTER_OFFICE_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_INTER_OFFICE_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_LOCAL_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_LOCAL_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_TAX_ID" type="strings" name="CUST_TAX_ID"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_FIRST_NAME" type="strings" name="CUST_FIRST_NAME"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_MIDDLE_NAME" type="strings" name="CUST_MIDDLE_NAME"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_LAST_NAME" type="strings" name="CUST_LAST_NAME"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_TITLE" type="strings" name="CUST_TITLE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_SUFFIX" type="strings" name="CUST_SUFFIX"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_SSN_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_SSN_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_PROFESSION" type="strings" name="CUST_PROFESSION"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_QUALIFICATION" type="strings" name="CUST_QUALIFICATION"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_DOB" type="strings" name="CUST_DOB"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_GENDER" type="strings" name="CUST_GENDER"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_MARITAL_STS" type="strings" name="CUST_MARITAL_STS"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_ALL_CURR_APPL_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_ALL_CURR_APPL_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_TAX_STS" type="strings" name="CUST_TAX_STS"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_LOCATION" type="strings" name="CUST_LOCATION"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_PIN_NUMBER" type="strings" name="CUST_PIN_NUMBER"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_GRP_COMP_CODE" type="strings" name="CUST_GRP_COMP_CODE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_GROUP_CODE" type="strings" name="CUST_GROUP_CODE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
            <field column="CUST_PAN_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_PAN_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CREDIT_DAYS" type="strings" name="CUST_CREDIT_DAYS"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_PASSPORT_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_PASSPORT_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_ASSR_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_ASSR_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CIVIL_ID" type="strings" name="CUST_CIVIL_ID"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CIVIL_ID_TYPE" type="strings" name="CUST_CIVIL_ID_TYPE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_REF_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_REF_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_MARKETER_CODE" type="strings" name="CUST_MARKETER_CODE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_PF_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_PF_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_COMM_REG_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_COMM_REG_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CORP_APPR_CUST_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_CORP_APPR_CUST_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_JOB" type="strings" name="CUST_JOB"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_NATIONALITY" type="strings" name="CUST_NATIONALITY"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_OCC_TYPE" type="strings" name="CUST_OCC_TYPE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CHANNEL" type="strings" name="CUST_CHANNEL"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_SUB_CHANNEL" type="strings" name="CUST_SUB_CHANNEL"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_TAX_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_TAX_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_EMAIL_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_EMAIL_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_SMS_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_SMS_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_VER_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_VER_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_RESIDENT_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_RESIDENT_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_OWN_AC_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_OWN_AC_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_OWN_CAR_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_OWN_CAR_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_OWN_HOUSE_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_OWN_HOUSE_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_OWN_REFRIGERATOR_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_OWN_REFRIGERATOR_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_OWN_TWO_WHEELER_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_OWN_TWO_WHEELER_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
           <field column="CUST_OWN_WASHING_MC_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_OWN_WASHING_MC_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_TRAVEL_ABROAD" type="strings" name="CUST_TRAVEL_ABROAD"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_PASSPORT_EXPIRY_DTM" type="strings" name="CUST_PASSPORT_EXPIRY_DTM"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CONTACT_TYPE" type="strings" name="CUST_CONTACT_TYPE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_STS" type="strings" name="CUST_STS"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_LEAD_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_LEAD_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_OTH_PROD_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_OTH_PROD_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_VIP_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_VIP_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_EMP_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_EMP_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CAPACITY" type="strings" name="CUST_CAPACITY"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CSI_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_CSI_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CSI_LAST_DTM" type="strings" name="CUST_CSI_LAST_DTM"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_REMARKS" type="strings" name="CUST_REMARKS"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_AUTO_REN_PROC_DAY" type="strings" name="CUST_AUTO_REN_PROC_DAY"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_NON_REN_NOTICE_DAY" type="strings" name="CUST_NON_REN_NOTICE_DAY"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_TIN" type="strings" name="CUST_TIN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_PREF_MODE_OF_PAY" type="strings" name="CUST_PREF_MODE_OF_PAY"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CR_UID" type="strings" name="CR_UID"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CR_DTM" type="strings" name="CR_DTM"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="UPD_UID" type="strings" name="UPD_UID"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="UPD_DTM" type="strings" name="UPD_DTM"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="WF_PROCESS_ID" type="strings" name="WF_PROCESS_ID"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_LEAD_CODE" type="strings" name="CUST_LEAD_CODE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_REG_EXP_DTM" type="strings" name="CUST_REG_EXP_DTM"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CIVIL_ID_EXPIRY_DTM" type="strings" name="CUST_CIVIL_ID_EXPIRY_DTM"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_PARENT_ACC" type="strings" name="CUST_PARENT_ACC"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_PARENT_ACC_ID" type="strings" name="CUST_PARENT_ACC_ID"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_TYPE" type="strings" name="CUST_TYPE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CAPITAL" type="strings" name="CUST_CAPITAL"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_ELECTRONIC_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_ELECTRONIC_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_CR_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_CR_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_BUSE_NATURE" type="strings" name="CUST_BUSE_NATURE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_PLACE_OF_ISSUE" type="strings" name="CUST_PLACE_OF_ISSUE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_NO_OF_EMP" type="strings" name="CUST_NO_OF_EMP"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_REVENUE" type="strings" name="CUST_REVENUE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />    
           <field column="CUST_ADDL_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_ADDL_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_OWNER_ID" type="strings" name="CUST_OWNER_ID"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_IQAMA_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_IQAMA_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_HIJRI" type="strings" name="CUST_HIJRI"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_EDUCAT_LVL" type="strings" name="CUST_EDUCAT_LVL"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_WORK_PLACE" type="strings" name="CUST_WORK_PLACE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_DFLT_CC_CODE" type="strings" name="CUST_DFLT_CC_CODE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_REG_FM_DTM" type="strings" name="CUST_REG_FM_DTM"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_ADDL_TYPE" type="strings" name="CUST_ADDL_TYPE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_BUS_NAT" type="strings" name="CUST_BUS_NAT"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_HIJRI_DTM" type="strings" name="CUST_HIJRI_DTM"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_THIRD_NAME" type="strings" name="CUST_THIRD_NAME"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_DB_CR_ACC_TYPE" type="strings" name="CUST_DB_CR_ACC_TYPE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_SUB_LED_TYPE" type="strings" name="CUST_SUB_LED_TYPE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_COMP_TYPE" type="strings" name="CUST_COMP_TYPE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_VIP_REMARKS" type="strings" name="CUST_VIP_REMARKS"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_BLOOD_GROUP" type="strings" name="CUST_BLOOD_GROUP"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_DEBIT_DAYS" type="strings" name="CUST_DEBIT_DAYS"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_DEBIT_LIMIT" type="strings" name="CUST_DEBIT_LIMIT"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_VAT_TYPE" type="strings" name="CUST_VAT_TYPE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_HIJRI_DOB" type="strings" name="CUST_HIJRI_DOB"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_PROSPECT_YN" type="strings" name="CUST_PROSPECT_YN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_PROSPECT_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_PROSPECT_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_PHONE_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_PHONE_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_MOBILE_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_MOBILE_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_ALTR_MOBILE_NO" type="strings" name="CUST_ALTR_MOBILE_NO"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_MAIL_ID" type="strings" name="CUST_MAIL_ID"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_ALTR_MAIL_ID" type="strings" name="CUST_ALTR_MAIL_ID"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_AR_FULL_NAME" type="strings" name="CUST_AR_FULL_NAME"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_ISSUED_IN" type="strings" name="CUST_ISSUED_IN"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_COMP_CLASS" type="strings" name="CUST_COMP_CLASS"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="REC_TYPE" type="strings" name="REC_TYPE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_REG_TO_DTM" type="strings" name="CUST_REG_TO_DTM"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           <field column="CUST_AGENCY_TYPE" type="strings" name="CUST_AGENCY_TYPE"  indexed="true" stored="true" />
           
      </entity> 
     
    </document>
    </dataConfig>
```

But the Data Import Handler UI Widget is not importing the Oracle DB Data , It simply blinks the Indexing text , but nothing happens , I am using Solr 8.4.1 for the above operation.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you've checked

- the SOLR logs,
- the connection parameters,
- Oracle DB host is reachable by the SOLR nodes,
- the Oracle DB driver is present (and loaded!) by the SOLR service. Oracle driver jar has to be inserted in "server/lib" path.
- the compatibility of the java version with which the SOLR service is running and the Oracle driver installed.